# Testing a component which calls an async function

Tags: javascript, reactjs, unit-testing, sinon, stub

I have a `react` component which calls an `async` function passed in as a prop and then calls another function in the `then` function.

I've trivialised it below as an illustration.

E.g.

```
const Form = ({ doSomething, closeModal }) => 
<form onSubmit={(e) => {doSomething().then(() => closeModal())
}}>
...
</form>
```

I am attempting to test that `closeModal` was called like so:

```
it('should doSomething then call closeModal', () => {

  const doSomethingStub = sinon.stub().resolves()
  const closeModalStub = sinon.stub()

  const props = {
    doSomething: doSomethingStub,
    closeModal: closeModalStub
  }

  const wrapper = shallow(<Form {...props}/>)

  wrapper.find(`form`).simulate(`submit`)

  expect(doSomethingStub.called).toEqual(true)
  expect(closeModalStub.called).toEqual(true)

})
```

In my example, only the first expectation is true. Have I done something wrong with the sinon.stub setup? or what I'm expecting? it feels like something minor but I can't pin it down

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're exactly right, it just needs a minor change:

`then` queues a callback for execution. Callbacks execute when the current synchronous code completes and the event loop grabs whatever is queued next.

The test is running to completion and failing before the callback queued by `then` from within `onSubmit()` has a chance to run.

Give the event loop a chance to cycle so the callback has a chance to execute and that should resolve the issue. That can be done by making your test function asynchronous and awaiting on a resolved promise where you want to pause the test and let any queued callbacks execute:

```
it('should doSomething then call closeModal', async () => {

  const doSomethingStub = sinon.stub().resolves()
  const closeModalStub = sinon.stub()

  const props = {
    doSomething: doSomethingStub,
    closeModal: closeModalStub
  }

  const wrapper = shallow(<Form {...props}/>)

  wrapper.find(`form`).simulate(`submit`);

  // Pause the synchronous test here and let any queued callbacks execute
  await Promise.resolve();

  expect(doSomethingStub.called).toEqual(true)
  expect(closeModalStub.called).toEqual(true)

});
```

Comment: Perfect, thanks, I knew I would be missing something stupid, the disconnect I had was that I thought `stub.resolves()` would return a promise which would resolve but I wasn't aware within a test how to `await` that specific promise.